# mahan many particle physics third edition problem 1.3

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, many-body, second-quantization

Im solving porblem 1.6 the book of many particle physics of mahan where i need to find the eigenvalues of the tight binding hamiltonian, for the nearest neighbours

\begin{equation}
w\sum_{i \delta}\left( a_{i}^{\dagger} b_{i+\delta}+ b_{i+\delta}^{\dagger}a_{i}\right)+\sum_{i}\left(A a^{\dagger}_{i}a_{i}+Bb^{\dagger}_{i}b_{i}\right)
\end{equation}

im been thinking that i just need to consider $\delta=0$, further i try to take the $\delta=0$ and $1$ therm, then represent the creation an destruction operators in the $k$ representation, but i dont know what is the answer of the problem, so i really want to know which is the answer of the problem.